# Running Cordova HelloWorld project on Ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, permissions

I've worked with Apache Cordova quite a bit on Windows but for some reason I can't get the project to run on Ubuntu.

I've setup the Android SDK correctly so `adb` and `android` both run from Terminal.

Here's the output I get when attempting to run the project on android.

```
josh@josh-ubuntu:~/Projects/hello$ cordova run android
Running command: /home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/run 

/home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/bin/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/build.template'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at /home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js:120:40
    at _fulfilled (/home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: /home/josh/Projects/hello/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Could it be something wrong with my file permissions?

Comment: How have you installed android sdk? From here it seems your user does not have permission to read sdk files...

Answer (score 0):

The log is saying that is a Permissions Problem!

Try to execute

sudo cordova run android

and if it lets you, then for sure it's a permission issue!

Comment: If I run ``sudo cordova build`` I get ``[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]`` sudo must be overriding my path. Also I shouldn't need ``sudo`` anyway. :/

Comment: I have a similar problem, I have changed the permissions (chmod -R 777) for the root folder created in the cordova create statement, I can then add the platform but I cannot run the device emulation, "ripple emulate -p 1234" will work instead but its not a great replacement